# Python: Change matrix size according to the size of target matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I would like to change matrix A to a size that match with matrix size B so that later on I can perform minus function on A - B.

```
from numpy import matrix
A = matrix([[7, 5]])             
B = matrix([[2, 0],[0, 0]])
```

The value 7 is used to deduct [2,0] and the value 5 is used to deduct [0,0].

How to transform matrix A into:

```
A = matrix([[7,7],[5,5]])
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Will matrix A always be smaller than or equal to B, in terms of size?

Comment: Yes. Always smaller or equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the shape of `A` is `(a1,a2)`, the shape of `B` is `(b1,b2)`, and you the shape of `A'` to be `(a1,b2)` (Like in your example), You can do this:

```
>>>from numpy import matrix,ones
>>>A = matrix([[7, 5]])
>>>B = matrix([[2, 0],[0, 0]])
>>>C = ones(A.shape)

>>>c_shape = (A.shape[0],B.shape[1])
>>>C = ones(c_shape)
>>>A.T*C
[[ 7.  7.]
[ 5.  5.]]
```

Comment: @Xiong89 does the conditions I wrote always hold? Else, can you give full example as to what should happen when these condition does not hold?